# React SSR - Empty HTML when SSR with D3. Using useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, server-side-rendering

I have some code: https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-server-side-rendering-xpjhl

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import { select } from "d3";

const D3Example = () => {
  const data = [25, 30, 45, 60, 20];
  const svgRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const svg = select(svgRef.current);
    svg
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .join("circle")
      .attr("r", value => value)
      .attr("cx", value => value * 2)
      .attr("cy", value => value * 2)
      .attr("stroke", "red");
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <svg ref={svgRef} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<D3Example />);
console.log(html);
```

I would expect the resulting HTML to contain the SVG element with stuff in it. Presumably I'm not understanding the `useEffect` hook. This code works fine when rendering client side, just not using `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` don't run during server side rendering, same with `componentDidMount`

Rendering svg on the server be sure not to use any width or height properties as they don't exist on the server

For charts I would suggest using https://www.npmjs.com/package/recharts which supports server side rendering, more info on it: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/71